# if $A$ and $C$ become $100A $ and $100C$ , what is the value of $z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, operations-research

i have a maximization problem

$max z=Cx$

s.t $ Ax\leq b$

$x\geq0  $

if A and C become $100*A$ and$ 100*C$

what is  the value of new $x=x'$ and new $z=z'$ ?

i think new z not changed and  new x become $(1/100)*x$

because new$B'^{-1}$ is $(1/00)*B^{-1}$

is this true?

Comment: Could you be consistent with your notation.  I don't know A and C and what is B? is it b or C is c?

Comment: C is  coefficient of objective function, b is right hand side, $B^{-1}$ is matrix of basics variable

Comment: You seem to mix capital and lower case letters indiscriminately.  $C \neq c, B \neq b$.  Is the raised $t$ a transpose or a power?  Which variables are vectors (if $t$ is a transpose) and which are scalars?  What is $1/00$?  Please proofread and correct.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of increasing C to 100C has a direct impact on Z in that sense that it will be 100Z.  The effect of increasing A to 100A has an indirect impact of reducing X  and thus reducing Z.  But this cannot be quantified as you would in the case of C.  The simultaneous increasing of C and A will have an increasing effect on z directionally but not directly quantifiable ( as the amount by which x reduces is not one to one).